# How to use Dynamic CSS or multimple CSS in single tag

Tags: css, reactjs

I am Trying to use more then one style means i want to apply dynamic CSS i am having a line i want to move the line from left:0 to Left:450.
And i want to set the height of the line means top:0 to Top:200

Means At First i want to move the line from top:0 to top:200
and at top:200 i want to Move the Line in Right Direction It means To move the line in Left:0 to Left:450
so how van i use both the styles in Single Object.

```html
<script src="react.development.js"></script>
<script src="babel.js"></script>
<script src="react-dom.development.js"></script>
<style>
    .arrow{
        width: 50px;
        border: 2px solid red;
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50px;
        left: 0px;


    }
    .wall1{
        margin-top: 25px;
          height: 50px;
          border: 2px solid green;
          display: inline block;
          position: absolute;
          left: 500px;
    }
    .wall2{
        margin-top: 80px;
          height: 60px;
          border: 2px solid green;
          display: inline block;
          position: absolute;
          left: 300px;
    }
    .wall3{
          margin-top: 160px;
          height: 60px;
          border: 2px solid green;
          display: inline block;
          position: absolute;
          left: 400px;
    }


</style>


<div id="root"></div>


<script type="text/babel">
class Shoot extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.FnGame=this.FnGame.bind(this);
        this.FnDown=this.FnDown.bind(this);
        this.FnUp=this.FnUp.bind(this);
       
        this.state={
            left:0,
            top:50
        }
    }

  

    FnGame(){
        let id=setInterval(()=> {
            this.setState({
                left:++this.state.left
            })
            if(this.state.left==450){
                clearInterval(id)
            }
        },12);
    }
    FnDown(){
        
        let id=setInterval(()=> {
            this.setState({
                top:++this.state.top
                

            })

            if(this.state.top==200){
                clearInterval(id)
            }
        },10);
    }

    FnUp(){
        let id=setInterval(()=> {
            this.setState({
                top:--this.state.top
            })
            if(this.state.top==50){
                clearInterval(id)
            }
        },10);
    }
 



    render(){
        return <div>
            <button onClick={this.FnUp} >Up</button>
            <button onClick={this.FnGame} >SHOOT..</button>
            <button onClick={this.FnDown} >Down</button>
            <div  style={{left:this.state.left}} className="arrow"></div>
            <div  style={{top:this.state.top}} className="arrow"></div>
            <div className="wall1"></div>
            <div className="wall2"></div>
            <div className="wall3"></div>
            </div>
        }

}

ReactDOM.render(<Shoot />,document.getElementById("root"));
</script>
```

Comment: You can use [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) package.